# center a div on page creates random pixel below class

Tags: css

I'm no pro at css and found a progress tracker I like, but need it centered on page. But whenever I center it I get a random pixel at bottom of first two arrows: (see screenshot)

I want it centered on page and am using margin auto with a hardcoded 380px. I'm sure the hardcoded 380px should be something not hardcoded but "auto" did same thing.

[image: the first two arros have pixel sticking down]

css:

```
div#wizard.wizard
    {
        width: 380px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

.wizard a 
    {
        padding: 12px 12px 10px 12px;
        margin-right:5px;
        background:#efefef;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }
.wizard a:before
    {
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        border-top: 20px inset transparent;
        border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
        border-left: 20px solid #fff;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
    }
.wizard a:after
    {
        width:0px;
        height:0px;
        border-top: 20px inset transparent;
        border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
        border-left: 20px solid #efefef;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 0;
        right: -20px;
        z-index:2;
    }
.wizard a:first-child:before {border:none;}
.wizard a:last-child:after {border:none;}

.wizard a:first-child
    {
        -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        border-radius:   4px 0 0 4px;
    }
.wizard a:last-child
    {
        -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    }

.wizard .badge {margin:0 5px 0 18px; position:relative; top:-1px;}
.wizard a:first-child .badge {margin-left:0;}

.wizard .current {background:#007ACC; color:#fff;}
.wizard .current:after {border-left-color:#007ACC;}
```

calling page:

```
 <div class="wizard" id="wizard">
    <a class="current"><span class="badge badge-inverse">1</span> Your Information</a>
    <a><span class="badge">2</span> Preview</a>
    <a><span class="badge">3</span> Your Copy</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This (http://jsfiddle.net/fhwwe/) is working fine in Chrome 22, Safari  6 and Firefox 16 (all Mac). Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome 28, firefox 22 on mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using

```
.wizard .badge { ... top: -1px; }
```

Maybe this is the reason why it looks as if the extra pixel is there. What happens if you set this to zero?

Add

```
.wizard a { height: 18px; }
```

Because you haven't specified the exact height, whilst the height of the two borders adds up to 40 pixels, the height of the button may still vary. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: It moves the 1, 2 and 3 down a pixel.